# Write vectors of different length into csv file

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, export

I have several vectors of different length to export.
First, I tried to make a data.frame of these, but they are in different length, so I can't.
Second, I tried use append=T when write.csv, however, all the vectors all in a single row instead of several column.

I want to export these vectors into CSV file with each vector in its own column.

Comment: You should post the code as an edit to this question. You also need to say what you mean by "columns" in reference to a csv file.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is vague, so I'll make some inferences:

1. The vectors are manually- and individually- handled; if there is a way to deal with them programmatically (such as a list of disparate vectors, or a naming convention that allows simple automation), it will make some of the below easier.
2. *"... each vector in its own column"* means that the columns are next to each other, not consecutive. I have dealt with CSV files that have multiple matrices with different numbers of columns; this is not normal, and not quite right.

Some data:

```
set.seed(42)
vec1 <- sample(100, size = 5)
vec2 <- sample(100, size = 8)
vec3 <- sample(100, size = 9)
```

In general, when you try to add columns to a matrix or data.frame in R, it really wants the number of rows (or length of the vector) to be convenient; when not, it complains. So, we can force it some.

```
df <- data.frame(vec1 = rep(NA, max(sapply(list(vec1, vec2, vec3), length))))
df[1:length(vec1), 1] <- vec1
df[1:length(vec2), 2] <- vec2
df[1:length(vec3), 3] <- vec3
df
##   V1 V2 V3
## 1 92 52 26
## 2 93 73 46
## 3 29 14 93
## 4 81 64 95
## 5 62 68 12
## 6 NA 44 99
## 7 NA 96 53
## 8 NA 87 85
## 9 NA NA 13
```

Now we can write it to a CSV file:

```
write.csv(df, file = 'somefile.csv', row.names = FALSE, na = '')
```

Note that I included `na = ''` as an option; otherwise, your CSV file will have `NA` strings in the extra space between the end of each vector and the end of the longest vector. Blanks are typically interpreted better (though that's up to you and/or with whom you share your data).